# How should strings be organized in ios 8 app?

Tags: ios, string, nslocalizedstring

So my main concern is being organized and doing it the right way. So I have a lot of strings in the app that I am working on. Some of the strings will be seen by the user but a lot of them are going to be internal to the app. So my question is how should I organize them all? I have been looking into NSLocalizedString which looks like a good offer but I just do not think that it makes sense to put all the strings that are not going to bee seen by the user into this file. What my understanding is, is that NSLocalizedString is made to create your app versatile for all languages. (Which I am still confused about how that works) and to reduce clutter, space etc. What I am currently thinking of doing is to put all the strings that will be seen by the user into the Localizable.strings file and all the other strings that are internal at the top of my files. Does this seem like the best practice? Am I missing anything? Any suggestions/tips would be a huge help.

Thank you prior for taking a minute to help a new developer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I declare all my internal strings as constants in the implementation of my classes

```
NSString *const some_string = @"Some String";
```

that way they autocomplete so I am more confident with the type safety.

If I need them from another class you can also expose them in the header file of the class where they're defined.

```
extern NSString *const some_string;
```

For user visible strings that you want to later translate, localizable.strings is definitely the best place.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking of doing. Thanks for a quick response!

Comment: Since these are constants, they should start with your prefix (recommended 3 letters) and then a capital letter, such as `MYASomeString` (rather than `some_string`). Look around in Cocoa for many examples of this pattern. This is an excellent pattern for dictionary keys or notification names (typically suffixed `Key` or `Notification`).